# How to test what the end of each element of a list is in python

Tags: python, string, list

I am new to coding so I apologize- I'm sure this solution can be found with just if statements and for statements.

I have a user inputted list of 10 string and i want to test if any of the words end in 'ly.'

```
list = [] 
ly= 'ly'
for l in range(10):
    us = [str(input("Enter a subject: "))]
    list.append(us)
for a in list:
    if ly in a:
       print (a, "is an adverb")
    else:
        print (a)
```

My code currently will only say ly is an adverb; however, it won't say swiftly is an adverb. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Python strings have a .endswith() method.

Comment: `sum(map(lambda x: x.endswith('ly'), lst)) > 0`

Comment: what do you mean by "however, it won't say swiftly is an adverb" ?

Comment: if i run the code and input a list of words like swiftly, quickly, ect. It will output them but it won't say they are adverbs. It will say just ly is an adverb though. I've been working on solving it with just for loops and if statements but I should learn the string commands too.

Comment: `us = [str(input("Enter a subject: "))]` should be just `us = str(input("Enter a subject: "))`. You are creating a list of lists instead of list of strings.

Comment: What do you want to check:  if a string ends with `ly`, or if a word is an adverb? Those are different tasks

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your primary issue is that you have a `list` of `list`s, not a `list` of `str`s, because of this line:

```
us = [str(input("Enter a subject: "))]
```

Those brackets are wrapping the `str` to make a one element `list`. Thus if you type `foo`, the `barly`, then `ly`, (we'll skip all 10), you get a `list`:

```
[["foo"], ["barly"], ["ly"]]
```

when you probably expected:

```
["foo", "barly", "ly"]
```

The problem is that the `in` check is checking the `list` wrapper's `in` check, not the `str`s, so it only matches on an actual `ly` (because `"ly"` is in the `list`), but not anything else (because they're not equal to `"ly"`).

Remove the brackets to make it:

```
us = input("Enter a subject: ")  # If this is Python 2, use raw_input, not input
```

then to make sure you're doing suffix checks (not just `ly` is anywhere in the string), change: `if ly in a:` to `if a.endswith("ly"):`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate your array and check if some of the string ends with 'ly'. You can use [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm).

```
str.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]])
```

Changing your code:

```
for a in list:
if a.endswith(ly):
   print (a, "is an adverb")
else:
    print (a)
```

Comment: `if ly.endswith(ly):`? :-)

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger, fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
ly = 'ly'
wordlist = [input("Enter a subject: ") for i in range(10)]
for a in wordlist:
    print(a, "is an adverb" if a.endswith(ly) else "")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two issues in your code.

1. You are using in which will check if the string 'ly' is contained within a given string, whether it is at the end or not.

You want to use str.endswith, e.g. `if a.endswith(ly)`

2. In the code:

`us = [str(input("Enter a subject: "))] 
list.append(us)`

us is a list containing the inputed string, instead of just the inputted string.  You are then adding this list to another list.  instead your code should just be 
`us = str(input("Enter a subject: "))`

(No surrounding brackets)

Comment: A 3rd issue is shadowing `list`